Unable to use CodeDomProvider in .Net 8.0.3
I'm trying to compile and execute (in Visual Studio 2022) an example about CsharpCodeGenerator.
The exception received is "Operation is not supported on this platform."
I've used NuGet package System.CodeDom 6.0.0 and 8.0.0
Any hint about ?
Thanks.
Livio
I need to dynamically generate some (simple) c# code to be execute in runtime.
It seems to me that it could be some .Net compatiblity issue about whose solution I have no idea.
What could it be the right ".Net"?
